# How are the spins of three quarks in a nucleon aligned?

Tags: quantum-spin, standard-model, quarks, protons

A proton is composed of uud. Are the two up quarks paired up to cancel each other's spin or are one up quark and one down quark paired up?

I know the three quarks may only carry a small proportion of the total proton spin. But they still need to be aligned somehow.

I see the following figure on http://www.lns.mit.edu/nig/programs. It seems in most cases the two protons in He3 are paired up. Could the quarks in a nucleon work in a similar way?

[image]

Comment: On the wiki, you can find exotic baryons differing from the proton/neutron only that they have +++ spin configuration. This results a highly unstable particle with spin 3/2, decaying in the order of $10^{-20} s$ to a proton/neutron.

Comment: @peterh The Delta baryons could probably be considered as a case where the three quarks are not paired at all. That is why they have spin 3/2.

Answer (score -1):

The wave function of a proton is $2|u\uparrow u\uparrow d\downarrow\rangle-|u\uparrow u\downarrow d\uparrow\rangle-|u\downarrow u\uparrow d\uparrow \rangle$... So the probability of having u paired up with d is 2/3, and that of having u paired up with u is 1/3.

Comment: [Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) you can get a latex tutorial to tune your formatting skills.